# I can still access MongoDB server with no authentication credentials

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I am able to login to the server with and without credentials.
Yes, I have checked other stackoverflow posts and multiple other forums and I have tried everything, any help is much appreciated, thank you!

My Config File:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
#  engine:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo


security:
authorization: "enabled"


#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

I have done the following and it still allows me to login with no authentication.

Added to mongod.conf:

```
security:
authorization: "enabled"
```

Added User:

```
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "admin",
    pwd: "MYPASSWORD",
    roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

Restarted Server:

```
 sudo service mongodb restart
```

Mongod.log:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.895+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.899+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"main","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.899+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.911+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.911+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.911+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.911+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.911+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":79368,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongodb","architecture":"64-bit","host":"localhost"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.911+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"6.0.5","gitVersion":"c9a99c120371d4d4c52cbb15dac34a36ce8d3b1d","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.911+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"22.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.911+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1","port":27017},"processManagement":{"timeZoneInfo":"/usr/share/zoneinfo"},"security":{"authorization":"enabled"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongodb"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.912+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20568,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Error setting up listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Address already in use"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.912+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.912+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4794602, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Attempting to enter quiesce mode"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.912+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":6371601, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FLE Crud thread pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.912+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.912+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.912+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.912+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.912+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.912+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.912+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.912+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.912+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.912+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.912+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":6278511, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the Change Stream Expired Pre-images Remover"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.912+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.912+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.912+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-24T06:18:47.913+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":48}}
```

Comment: Yes, you can connect (almost) every time to a MongoDB without credentials. However, you cannot execute any command apart from harmless command like `db.help()`, `db.listCommands()`, `db.getMongo()`, etc.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit is right !

Comment: I was able to connect, change, delete, documents, I actually am just now trying to add authorization because someone got in and tried to hold the data for ransom.

Comment: This should not be the case. Did you create the user in `admin` database? You can check loaded parameters with `db.serverCmdLineOpts()`, what is the output?

Comment: {
  argv: [ '/usr/bin/mongod', '--bind_ip', '0.0.0.0' ],
  parsed: { net: { bindIp: '0.0.0.0' } },
  ok: 1
}

Comment: Please put such information in the question instead of adding comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response from `db.serverCmdLineOpts()`:

```
{ argv: [ '/usr/bin/mongod', '--bind_ip', '0.0.0.0' ], parsed: { net: { bindIp: '0.0.0.0' } }, ok: 1 }
```

As you see it did not read your config file at all! Looks like you started `mongod` without any parameters (i.e. without authentication) and then you try to start again with `service mongodb start`. This does not work, you can see error in logfile

```
"msg":"Error setting up listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Address already in use"}}}
```

means you try to start 'mongod' but it is already running. Thus you did not change anything. As you see in the last line of your logfile, the `mongod` shuts down.

Be aware, the default `dbPath` is `/data/db` but in your config you set `/var/lib/mongodb`. You may have inconsistent data if you mixed them.

**Solution**

- Stop **ALL** `mongod` processes! Verify with `ps` command, that no `mongod` process is running.
- Edit you config file, I assume it is clear which parameters you have to set
- Start the `mongod` service. Use one of these commands

  ```
  service mongodb start

  mongod --config <full path to your mongod.conf file>
  ```

Create the admin user and verify settings with `db.serverCmdLineOpts()`

Comment: I have tried what you told me to do and I am still able to access it with no username and password.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have tried what you told me"? I did not give any advice, I only told you what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things that could go wrong, please check the config file permission as well.

Make sure the string are inside ".

Based on their [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/)

> YAML does not support tab characters for indentation: use spaces instead.

```
storage:
  dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb"

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: "/usr/share/zoneinfo"


security:
  authorization: "enabled"
```

Comment: This does not work for me either.

Comment: I just now added Mongod.log, is there anything in the log that is not supposed to be there?